# Disable all shortcuts that include option key modifier only, in VSCode on mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to mass disable all keyboards shortcuts in VS Code on the Mac, that only use the option key as a modifier?

VS Code essentially has a breaking functionality on the Mac, whereby it uses the option key as a command trigger, even not when in combination with ctrl or command keys. This means that any characters only accessible by the option key aren't accessible. For example, on the US keyboard this mean I can't use 'option-m' to type in the 'µ' symbol or the accent dead-keys.

I have been told I just need to adjust the default short-cuts, but that will be a lot if I can't do it in batch, hence asking this question.

Note, my current workaround it to type these keys in Chrome and then copy/paste them, which is far from ideal.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this, but you can install an extension that emulates the keymap of some other editor or IDE ("Preferences / Migrate keyboard shortcuts from…" provides quick access) and at least the IDEA set gets Option right on Mac.